# Why are the items not appearing in the table?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm creating a point of sale using Django, a part arrived here that the items are not showing up, since I already registered them... Could someone help me?

A note: I'm Brazilian, my code is in the language, but I think there will be no problems.

Here's the codes:

This is the models part, which is inside the 'registration' app. I want this information to appear in another app called 'pages' inside, of course, the folder called 'templates'..

```
from django.db import models

class ListaProdutos(models.Model):
    nome_produto = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Produto')
    quantidade_produto = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Qntd.')
    custo_venda = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='Custo/Venda')
    fornecedor = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Fornecedor')
    data_adicao = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Data de Adição')

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {} {} {} {}".format(self.nome_produto, self.quantidade_produto, self.custo_venda, self.fornecedor, self.data_adicao)

class ListaDespesas(models.Model):
    nome_despesa = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Despesas')
    quantidade_despesa = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Qntd.')
    custo = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Custo')
    tipo_gasto = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Tipo de Gasto')
    data_atualizacao = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Data de Atualização')

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {} {} {} {}".format(self.nome_despesa, self.quantidade_despesa, self.custo, self.tipo_gasto, self.data_atualizacao)
```

Still in the 'registration' app, only in the urls part:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import ProdutoCreate, DespesaCreate
from .views import ProdutoUpdate, DespesaUpdate
from .views import ProdutoDelete, DespesaDelete
from .views import ProdutoList, DespesaList



urlpatterns = [
    path('cadastrar/produto', ProdutoCreate.as_view(), name='cadastrar-produto'),
    path('cadastrar/despesas', DespesaCreate.as_view(), name='cadastrar-despesa'),

    path('editar/produto/<int:pk>/', ProdutoUpdate.as_view(),name='editar-produto'),
    path('editar/despesa/<int:pk>', DespesaUpdate.as_view(),name='editar-despesa'),

    path('excluir/produto/<int:pk>/', ProdutoDelete.as_view(),name='excluir-produto'),
    path('excluir/despesa/<int:pk>', DespesaDelete.as_view(),name='excluir-despesa'),
    
    path('gastos/',ProdutoList.as_view(), name='lista-produto'),
    path('gastos/',DespesaList.as_view(), name='lista-despesa'),


]
```

In 'register' in the views part:

```
from multiprocessing import context
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from .models import ListaDespesas, ListaProdutos
from django.urls import reverse_lazy




""" Views """

class ProdutoCreate(CreateView):
    model = ListaProdutos
    fields = ['nome_produto', 'quantidade_produto', 'custo_venda', 'fornecedor', 'data_adicao']
    template_name = 'cadastro/form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('vendas')

class DespesaCreate(CreateView):
    model = ListaDespesas
    fields = ['nome_despesa', 'quantidade_despesa', 'custo', 'tipo_gasto', 'data_atualizacao']
    template_name = 'cadastro/form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('vendas')


""" Update """

class ProdutoUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = ListaProdutos
    fields = ['nome_produto', 'quantidade_produto', 'custo_venda', 'fornecedor', 'data_adicao']
    template_name = 'cadastro/form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('vendas')

class DespesaUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = ListaDespesas
    fields = ['nome_despesa', 'quantidade_despesa', 'custo', 'tipo_gasto', 'data_atualizacao']
    template_name = 'cadastro/form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('vendas')


""" Delete """

class ProdutoDelete(DeleteView):
    model = ListaProdutos
    template_name = 'cadastro/form-excluir.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('vendas')

class DespesaDelete(UpdateView):
    model = ListaDespesas
    template_name = 'cadastro/form-excluir.html'
    succes_url = reverse_lazy('vendas')


""" Lista """

class ProdutoList(ListView):
    model = ListaProdutos
    template_name = 'paginas/gastos.html'

class DespesaList(ListView):
    model = ListaDespesas
    template_name = 'paginas/gastos.html'
```

Finally, inside the 'paginas' app, inside the templates folder, inside the 'pages' directory, the 'gastos.html' template:

```
{% extends 'paginas/modelo.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block titulo %}
<title>PDV|Gastos</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block conteudo %}

<div class="home_content">
    <div class="conteudo_pagina">

        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <tr>
                    <th>Código</th>
                    <th>Produto</th>
                    <th>Qntd.</th>
                </tr>

                {% for produto in object_list %}

                <tr>
                    <td>{{ produto.pk }}</td>
                    <td>{{ produto.nome_produto }}</td>
                    <td>{{ produto.quantidade_produto }}</td>
                </tr>

                {% empty %}
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">Nenhum campo registrado</td>
                </tr>


                {% endfor %}

                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-striped">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Despesa</th>
                            <th>Qntd.</th>
                            <th>Custo</th>
                        </tr>
        
                        {% for despesa in object_list %}
        
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ despesa.nome_despesa }}</td>
                            <td>{{ despesa.quantidade_despesa }}</td>
                            <td>{{ despesa.custo }}</td>
                        </tr>
        
                        {% empty %}
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3">Nenhum campo registrado</td>
                        </tr>
        
        
                        {% endfor %}






            </table>
        </div>










</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Here is the image from the website:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTXyH.png)

Comment: My preference is to declare `context_object_name = 'name_of_object'` and then explicitly refer to the object name that in the view's for loop. If I were encountering this I would debug by starting with running a for loop with a print statement to each querylist element in the view.

Comment: I've never seen this method you mentioned, how could I be doing it?
Does this form enter the views part of the app?
Me doing it the way you told me, would I have to edit something in my code?

Comment: You can declare the attribute `context_object_name` in the ListView (along with `Model`, `template_name`, `fields` and/or `form_class`). What this does is allow you to specify the name of the object list being passed to the template. See documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#viewing-subsets-of-objects

Comment: Looks like you are also trying to use the object_list variables to try to get queries from 2 different models.   You def need to use the get_context method and query at least one of them and add to the context dictionary.  This might help: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-pass-additional-context-into-a-class-based-view-django/